# replacing a value in a string - Python

Tags: python

Thank you for sharing the knowledge.
I have a problem figuring out how to replace a value on a string.

for example

```
def replace(a, old, new):
  a.replace(old, new)
  return a 

replace('xy naxe is Exxa', 'x', 'm')
```

when I run this it returns the original without any replacements.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This isn't valid Python--can you clarify? `replace` doesn't mutate the string object it's called on. Thanks.

Comment: `replace` returns new string. Strings in python are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

Just do :

```
x = "xy naxe is Exxa".replace('x','m')
```

**Output**

```
"my naxe is Exxa"
```

Answer (score 0):

Python strings are immutable. You can't make in-place replacements in Python.

`a.replace(old, new)` will return a new string, it won't update `a`.

So you need to return the result of this method. Because this method will have no impact on `a`.

Comment: Thank you I ended up making it assigning it to a new variable then calling it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just execute `.replace` on them:

```
"xy naxe is Exxa".replace('x','m')
```

If x and m are variables:

```
"xy naxe is Exxa".replace(x,m)
```

It will return new string, not change original string because python strings are immutable.

Comment: Ohhh I understand! Thank you.